# Initializing and using dynamic arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, initialization

In my code, I am trying to create a dynamic array with initArray function, and in main I would like to use this initialized array. However, whenever i called the initialized array in main, it is giving me an error.

Here is what i tried:

```
void main() 
{
    int *a = NULL;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter size:";
    cin>>n;
    initArray(a,n);
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout<<a[j]<<endl;//Crashes here
    }
}
void initArray(int *A, int size)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    A = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand()%10;
    }
}
```

When i do initArray part in main, it works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use std::vector<T> rather than C style raw arrays is probably a better idea. (As is indenting your code correctly)

Comment: @Yacoby I want to use the array rather than vectors. I just want to know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I know, but this isn't about that right now. Thanks though.

Comment: @LuckySlevin: that's why I wrote it in a comment an not in an answer. :)

Comment: Another aside: you should call `srand` only once, not at every call to `initArray`, otherwise, if you call it more than once per second, you will always get the same numbers.

Comment: @LuckySlevin: That's exactly what you're doing wrong. Fiddling with dynamic C-style arrays is a hassle, and there are *many* mistakes to make. You're doing yourself a favor in using the standard containers.

Comment: The mixture of C and C++ suggests that you are learning C++ from a very poor source. Do yourself a favor and buy [a decent book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. the function accepts a pointer. When you write `A = ...` you're only changing the copy of the pointer that gets passed to you by value. You could use `void initArray(int* &A, int size)` instead, or have the function return a pointer.
2. if that's the full code, you might need a forward declaration of the `initArray` function.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. That's what i want to hear. I will give it a try. And the second part, it's not full code, i declared initArray function.

Answer (score 5):

> What am i doing wrong?

Not using `std::vector` is what you're doing wrong.

That aside, assuming this is for learning or homework or something:

```
initArray(a,n);
```

This line *copies* the `int` pointer `a`. The copy inside the function gets assigned, and the one in main will remain empty. You need to use pass-by-reference, either through C++ references or C style with pointers:

```
void initArray(int*& a, int size){
  // everything the same
}
```

This will modify the int pointer in main without any other changes.

```
void initArray(int** a, int size){
  // need to dereference the pointer-to-pointer to access the int pointer from main
  *a = new int[size];

  for(/*...*/){
   (*a)[i] = /*...*/;
  }
}
```

For this one, you'll need to change the call side too:

```
initArray(&a, n); // pass pointer to a
```

Now one last thing: `main` doesn't even know that `initArray` even exists. You need to put it above `main` or atleast forward declare it:

```
void initArray(int*& a, int size); // forward declaration

int main(){
  // ...
}

void initArray(int*& a, int size){
  // ...
}
```

And one last thing, you'll need to `delete[]` the array in main.

Comment: Thanks I already accepted another answer. I will give vote up for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `initArray` function definition above `main` or at least declare it above `main`.

Also note that the assignment `A = new int[size];` only modifies the local variable `A` inside the function `initArray`. It has no effect on the `a` inside `main` because pointers are passed by value. You need to either pass a reference or a pointer to the pointer, or better yet, return the pointer:

```
int* initArray(int size)   // note: one less parameter
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int* A = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand()%10;
    }
    return a;   // note: return the pointer
}
```

And then write `a = initArray(n);` inside `main`. Also, don't forget `delete[] a;` inside `main`!

And of course the usual advice, don't use raw pointers to dynamic arrays, use `std::vector` instead. But since I guess this is homework for a crappy C++ course, you probably have no choice.

Comment: Thanks I already accepted another answer. I will give vote up for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a copy of your pointer to `initArray`, make it a reference `initArray(int *&A, int size)`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void initArray(int *&A, int size); // put the declaration of function here


int main() 
{
    int *a = 0;

    int n;
    cout << "Enter size:";
    cin >> n;

    initArray(a,n);

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout<<a[j]<<endl;
    }

    delete[] a; // delete your array before exiting the program
}

// pass it as a reference to pointer
void initArray(int *&A, int size)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    A = new int[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand()%10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I already accepted another answer. I will give vote up for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you cna change the dclaration of initArray :

```
void initArray(int* &A, int size)
```

in your initial code, the array is not filled in.  because, A array is a copy of the main a array. so the a array remains equals to null.
you have then the choice between of passing a by reference "int* &A" as i did or by adress : "int** A"